# Cómo colocar contendido dentro de un div centrado pero con texto justificado?

Tags: html5, css3

Mi idea es tener un contenedor `div` dentro de este `div` todo el contexto o datos deben estar centrados o en el medio del `div`, pero que no afecte a ciertos contenidos por decir el texto deseo que este justificado.

Este es mi código:

```css
.grid-x2 {
    border: solid;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border: 1px solid #b7d4da;
    height: 600px;
}
.plan-info-agile {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.check-services {
    color: #5a7177;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 17px;
    background: url(assets/img/system/check-services.svg) left center no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-x2 right">
 <div class="plan-info-agile">
  <p><span class="check-services">Services 1</span></p>
  <p><span class="check-services">Services 2</span></p>
  <p><span class="check-services">Services 3</span></p>
  <p><span class="check-services">Services 4</span></p>
  <p><span class="check-services">Services 5</span></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Lo que deseo lograr es lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin tener que usar la propiedad `padding-left:;` con valores personalizados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.grid-x2 {
    border: solid;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border: 1px solid #b7d4da;
    height: 600px;
}
.plan-info-agile {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.check-services {
    color: #5a7177;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 17px;
    background: url(assets/img/system/check-services.svg) left center no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-x2 right">
 <div class="plan-info-agile">
  <p><span class="check-services">Services 1</span></p>
  <p><span class="check-services">Services 2</span></p>
  <p><span class="check-services">Services 3</span></p>
  <p><span class="check-services">Services 4</span></p>
  <p><span class="check-services">Services 5</span></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Creo que esto es lo que buscas, a las etiquetas `p` las tratas con `display: flex`, y remueves el `padding-left` a tus elementos `.check-services`

Comment: Hola @Edwin Sí exactamente gracias :)